# PyQt5. Converted .ui file into py, but in the editor there are a lot of errors

Tags: python, pyqt5, designer

I am a beginner in the Python world.
So, i have made a couple of forms in the `PyQt5` designer, saved them (the `.ui` files) and after that, of course i've tried to convert it into `.py` files so i can use it. But for some reason when i open the generated `.py` file in the editor there are a lot of errors. May be i haven't installed something or idk. Thanks.

Screenshots with errors:

[image: Errors]

If i'm not wrong, these imports are resources:

[Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chs1L.png)

This is the .py file:

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1280, 720)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QWidget#centralwidget\n"
"{\n"
"    background-image: url(:/BGHD/BgHD.png);\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 560, 251, 81))
        self.label.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/mmenu/Mmenu.png);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.computer_score_lb = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.computer_score_lb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 181, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Open Sans")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.computer_score_lb.setFont(font)
        self.computer_score_lb.setObjectName("computer_score_lb")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.computer_score_lb.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Calculatorul:"))
import BGHD_rc
import Logo_rc
import Start_rc
import mmenu_rc
import quit_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It seems you're using resource files, you should convert them using the `pyrcc5` utility. Note that you normally don't need so many resource files.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you.